# Is it valid to modify array elements while iterating with 'enhanced for' in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, syntax

Cosider this code:

```
    for (int value : values) {
        values[value] = -values[value] - 1;
    }
```

Is it guaranteed to pick updated values when the iteration process reaches appropriate elements?

Experimentally I figured ut that it works as expected (iteration yields the updated values).

Also from [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) I can conclude that it should work:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

I just wonder, if there is an 'official' confirmation that it's valid and guaranteed to pick the updated values?

*Update:*
Excluded according to comments:

> I am in doubt because analogous code would be invalid for e.g. `ArrayList`.

Comment: "equivalent" == "behaves exactly the same", so that part\* of the spec is the  'official' confirmation that it's valid and guaranteed to pick the updated values. Although the part of the spec you quoted is applicable to Iterable's, not arrays - that's further down.

Comment: What do you mean "would be invalid for e.g. ArrayList"? `List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1));
    for (int value : values) {
        values.set(value, values.get(value) + 1);
    }` works perfectly fine. You obviously can't use `[]` on a List, but that's unrelated to the enhanced for loop.

Comment: @Dukeling, I mean `The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.` Apparently, `ArrayList#set` is not a `structural modification` , and so my analogy was admittedly wrong: one cannot structurally modify a Java array.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, it is guaranteed to pick up the updated value.

Long answer: an enhanced `for` on an array is equivalent to this code (see [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), scroll down to "Otherwise, the Expression necessarily has an array type" part):

```
T[] #a = Expression;
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    ...
}
```

Therefore, it behaves the same way as if the array was iterated using an index.

**Note:** One thing that would be illegal is replacing the whole array that you are iterating with a new array object, i.e. assigning `values = new int[...]` has a potential of going past the end of the newly allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

Reading source code can confirm this.

Yes it is.

Just look at the [source code of `next()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr) method. It keep on getting the data from ArratList

```
Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
```

Full method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
753         public E More ...next() {
754             checkForComodification();
755             int i = cursor;
756             if (i >= size)
757                 throw new NoSuchElementException();
758             Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
759             if (i >= elementData.length)
760                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
761             cursor = i + 1;
762             return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
763         }
```

That tells that, if you are modifying an element in side ArrayList while iterating, you see those changes right away.